# return Promise with for each

Tags: foreach, promise

I'm developing a system in Node.js, and the situation is this: I have a Promise that returns me an Id list, and in return of that Promise (then) I call another method that needs to execute a query for each one Of the items returned in the first method.

What would be the best way to do this?

My code is like this:

```
  checkLastPosition(list) {
    let returnList = new Array();
    var actualDate = new Date();
    list.forEach(function (item) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            pool.getConnection(function (err, connection) {

                if (err)
                    reject(err);

                let sql = ' select * from posicao loc';
                sql += ' where veiculoid = ?';
                sql += ' and loc.dataHora = (select max(dataHora) from posicao where veiculoId = loc.veiculoId)';
                sql += ' order by loc.veiculoid, datahora desc';

                connection.query(sql, item.veiculoid, function (err, rows) {

                    connection.release();

                    if (err)
                        reject(err);

                    resolve(rows[0]);
                });
            });
        }).then(result => {


            if (!result) {
                returnList.push(item.veiculoId);
            } else {
                if (new Date(result.dataHora.toLocaleString()) <= actualDate.setMinutes(actualDate.getMinutes() - 10)) {
                    returnList.push(item.veiculoId);
                }
            }
        });

    }, this);
}
```

Comment: Use `map` instead of `forEach`, and apply `Promise.all` to the resulting array of promises.

Comment: How do I do this?

Answer (score 3):

First, convert `list.forEach()` invocation to `list.map()`. Using `map()` you can build an array of promises. Every promise contains the result of the query.

Save this list of promises in a variable called `queries`. Then use `Promise.all()` which will produce a resolved/rejected promise when all the promises in `queries` are resolved or at least one is rejected.

Doing that, you can attach a `then` call to `Promise.all()`, the resolve callback will receive an array containing the result of the queries. Here you can loop over the results, build your `returnList` array and return it.

The `returnList` will be wrapped by `then()` in a promise, this promise will be returned to the caller of `checkLastPosition` method:

```
checkLastPosition(list) {
    let queries = list.map(function (item) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            pool.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
                if (err) reject(err);

                let sql = ' select * from posicao loc';
                sql += ' where veiculoid = ?';
                sql += ' and loc.dataHora = (select max(dataHora) from posicao where veiculoId = loc.veiculoId)';
                sql += ' order by loc.veiculoid, datahora desc';

                connection.query(sql, item.veiculoid, function (err, rows) {
                    connection.release();
                    if (err) reject(err);

                    resolve(rows[0]);
                });
            });
        });
    }, this);

    return Promise.all(queries).then(results => {
        let returnList = new Array();
        var actualDate = new Date();
        results.forEach(result => {
            if (!result) {
                returnList.push(item.veiculoId);
            } else {
                if (new Date(result.dataHora.toLocaleString()) <= actualDate.setMinutes(actualDate.getMinutes() - 10)) {
                    returnList.push(item.veiculoId);
                }
            }
        });
        return returnList;
    });
}
```

Comment: Okay, and how do I get back the returnList?

Comment: I have updated the answer to show you how to return `returnList`.

Comment: I accepted, but due to my poor reputation will not stand out, sorry.

Comment: @Andrea I just wanted to say thanks this answer really helped!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using [mysqljs](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql).

Instead of creating several promises that each perform one SQL query, I would instead just create one promise, and let the SQL query perform in `in` check on the whole input list. This way you will only query the database once.

I think you also have an issue with `actualDate`, since in this expression you actually modify that variable:

```
actualDate.setMinutes(actualDate.getMinutes() - 10)
```

Every time that expression is evaluated, it subtracts 10 minutes from it, so you end up comparing with -10, -20, -30, ... minutes.

Here is some -- untested -- code illustrating the idea:

```
checkLastPosition(list) {
    var actualDate = new Date();
    // Be careful: setMinutes will mutate the variable -- don't repeat it:
    actualDate.setMinutes(actualDate.getMinutes() - 10);

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
            if(err)
                reject(err);
            let sql =  ' select * from posicao loc';
                sql += ' where veiculoid in (' + // use IN operator and inject escaped list of ID values
                            list.map(item => connection.escape(item.veiculoid)).join(',') + ')';
                sql += ' and loc.dataHora = (select max(dataHora) from posicao where veiculoId = loc.veiculoId)';
                sql += ' order by loc.veiculoid, datahora desc';
            connection.query(sql, function(err, rows) { // no more bound variables
                connection.release();
                if(err)
                    reject(err);
                resolve(rows); // all rows
            });
        });  
    }).then(result => {
        // Identify which records should be excluded, and make a Set of them, for faster lookup
        const toExclude = 
            new Set(result.filter( record => new Date(record.dataHora.toLocaleString()) > actualDate )
                          .map( record => record.veiculoid )
                    );
        // Take the original list of items, and exclude the ones from it according to that Set:
        return list.map(item => item.veiculoid).filter(veiculoid => !toExclude.has(veiculoid));
    });
}
```

Note that I stepped away from using `?` in the query, as with a dynamic list of IDs, you would need to pass the same number of these. As I read in the documentation that the API just uses `connection.escape()` internally, I just used that function instead of `?`.

Comment: I decided not to use "in" because the select was too slow, but thanks for the suggestion

Comment: `in` should not be slower than the time for doing *n* individual queries with `=`. If it is really slower than that, then you might need to look at indexes, because that is not normal.